# draw object oriented lineTo using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, oop, canvas

was wondering how to use moveTo, lineTo and arc using javascript & html5 using oop.
Seen lots of examples drawing fillrect etc but that seems simpler than using the lineTo etc.

Is it a big difference in how i should proceed?

Comment: You question is to general, please rephrase it to get answers. You can look at questions with answers to get a feeling.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DhQmrHAG maybe its more clear what im asking for if i paste an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas-api is pretty low-level, it's a so called immediate mode api which is indeed more function-based then object oriented.

"Immediate mode" means that the api does not keep track of what has been drawn on the canvas. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_%28computer_graphics%29)

A classical object oriented pattern, that can be set on top of such an api as abstraction layer, would be a SceneGraph. The basic GoV-Pattern to implement that, would be the composite-pattern.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern

Another option is, to use a library like fabricjs which tries to keep track of the drawn objects. The main UseCase of Fabricjs is a Vector-painting application running in the browser, so I'm not shure if this will fit your needs.

I personally prefer the SceneGraph in most cases, but that depends on your UseCase.